# String Not Defined

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm new in nuxt and Vue, I'm following a nuxt tutorial I downloaded but I'm getting an error of `string not defined`.

How can I solve this?

```
props: {
  title: {
    type: string,
    required: true
  },
  previewtext: {
    type: string,
    required: true
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 3):

Hello @Irene Mercy You must write your string like this "String" not this "string"
refers to documentations .

```
props: {
 title: String,
 likes: Number,
 isPublished: Boolean,
 commentIds: Array,
 author: Object
}
```

https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your response and for the link, it will help me learn more.